# ListView inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerViewAdapter to fill recycler view.
Inside each recyclerItem must be list with items, and I decided to make it listView.

so inside onBindViewHolder of recyclerView i create new cursor, make new query (with help of contentResolver) and than i need to fill my listView with this data.

here is some my code:

```
Cursor.moveToFirst();
        int size = Cursor.getCount();
        if (size > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                Cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                setCurrentItem();
            }
        }

private void setCurrentItem(){
        View View = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_test, null);
        mLogo = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.iv_Item_logo);
        mName = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardItem_Name);
        mNumber = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardItem_Number);
        mBlocked = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Item_blocked);
        mDate = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Item_Date);

        String Name = Cursor.getString(AccountsFragment.NAME);
        String Numb = Cursor.getString(AccountsFragment.NUMBER);
        Numb = USB_Converter.Numbers(Numb);
        String Date = Cursor.getString(AccountsFragment.DATE);
        Date = USB_Converter.friendlyDate(Date);
        int Status = Cursor.getInt(AccountsFragment.STATUS);
        if (Status == UserAccountsEntry.STATUS_ID_ACTIVE){
            mBlocked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mBlocked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mName.setText(Name);
        mNumber.setText(Numb);
        mDate.setText(Date);

        mHolder.mListView.addFooterView(cardView);
    }
```

this works without any errors, but it's does not show listView...

any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT**
listView.xml:

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/lv_accountList"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
 />
```

Comment: Your string 'Name' gets the values from the database. Whereas you use another string 'cardName' for the 'setText()'

Comment: mistake in question, fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't show the content of list_item_test.xml, but you'll probably need to give the inner ListView an absolute height in dp (or give it's parent an absolute height and then use `match_parent` on the ListView).

You can't use `wrap_content` for a ListView (it will shrink to 0 height), and you can't use `match_parent` if the parent doesn't have an independently derived or explicitly declared height.

Comment: As I said, you can't use wrap_content for the height of a ListView. Try a fixed height, or match_parent